# using aggregate function with SQL having clause

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, having

can anyone tell me, why is this query giving an error

Write a query to find the maximum total earnings (earnings) for all employees as well as the total number of employees (num_employees) who have maximum total earnings.
total earnings = months worked *salary
We define an employee's total earnings to be their monthly (salary×months) worked

```
SELECT
 (salary*months) as earnings 
 ,count(*) as num_employees
FROM employee
group by salary*months  
having max(salary * months)=salary*months
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Update your question with the error message. I'm guessing that your DBMS doesn't allow group by/having to use calculated columns - in which case you'd need to put this in an inner query and then select from it in an outer query

Comment: Instead of having, you can `order by earnings desc fetch first 1 row only`, or similar.

Comment: If it is SQL Server then top 1 with ties should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

there is a logic issue in your code. you see, the `HAVING` clause is used to perform filtering on the results of the grouped data, so using `MAX` in the having clause might not get you the results you expect.

if you want to find the maximum total earnings and the number of employees with that maximum total earnings, you can use a subquery to first find the maximum total earnings and then join it back to the original table like this:

```
SELECT
  e.salary * e.months as earnings,
  COUNT(*) as num_employees
FROM employee e
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(salary * months) as max_earnings
  FROM employee
) max_earnings_query ON e.salary * e.months = max_earnings_query.max_earnings
GROUP BY e.salary * e.months;
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by earnings descending. Pick the first row only, the one with the highest earnings:

ANSI/ISO SQL:

```
SELECT
 (salary*months) as earnings 
 ,count(*) as num_employees
FROM employee
group by salary*months  
order by earnings desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Instead of `FETCH FIRST`, some non-standard alternatives are `LIMIT 1` and `SELECT TOP 1`.